# Equation derived from the Gaussian equation.

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I tryed resolve the follow problem, but I get not. Someone can help me ?

Let be $N^3$ a smooth Riemannian manifolds and let be $\Sigma^2$ a closed and embedded minimal surface of $ N $. Show that

$$K_\Sigma = K_N -2Ric^N - | A_\Sigma | ^ 2. $$

Where $ K $ is Gauss curvature and $A_\Sigma$ is second fundamental form
 of $\Sigma$.
Hint: Took the trace in Gauss equation twice and useding  that $\Sigma$ is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is confusing to me, but I think your question follows from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840671/nice-identity-the-norm-of-the-second-fundamental-form-and-scalar-ricci-mean). Basically, the following identity follows from the Gauss equation:
$$ R_N - 2 \text{Ric}_N(n_\Sigma,n_\Sigma) - |A_\Sigma|^2 = 2K_\Sigma - H_\Sigma^2 $$
where $R_N$ is the scalar curvature, $n_\Sigma$ is a normal to $\Sigma$, $|A_\Sigma|$ is the Frobenius norm of the second fundamental form, and $K_\Sigma,H_\Sigma$ are the Gaussian and mean curvatures of the embedded hypersurface.

Since $\Sigma$ is minimal, $H_\Sigma = 0$.
$$
R_\Sigma = R_N - 2 \text{Ric}_N(n_\Sigma,n_\Sigma) - |A_\Sigma|^2
$$
where we note that $R_\Sigma=2K_\Sigma$ [because $\Sigma$ is 2D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397064/relationship-between-ricci-and-scalar-curvatures-in-2-dimentions?rq=1). Using $K_\Sigma$ instead makes the equation off by a coefficient of $2$, so I suspect you just mean this, or your notation is different.