# Relationship between Ricci and Scalar curvatures in 2 dimentions

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

My book says that the Ricci curvature is defined as:
$$\rho(X,Y)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle R_{X E_m}E_m,Y \rangle $$ where {$E_1, ... ,E_n$} are orthonormal.
Also
$$s=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\rho(E_j,E_j)$$

I have to proof that $\rho(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}s\langle X,Y\rangle$ for   $n=2$

What I have is:
$$\rho(X,Y)=\langle R_{X E_1}E_1,Y \rangle+\langle R_{X E_2}E_2,Y \rangle$$
$$\frac{1}{2}s\langle X,Y\rangle=\langle R_{E_1 E_2}E_2,E_1 \rangle\langle X,Y \rangle$$
Where I have used that $\langle R_{E_1 E_2}E_2,E_1 \rangle=\langle R_{E_2 E_1}E_1,E_2 \rangle$ and $\langle R_{E_1 E_1}E_1,E_1 \rangle=0$

Any idea about how can I continue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's very easy (although probably a bit tedious) to work this all out in coordinates. We consider the $(0,4)$-type Riemann curvature tensor, $R(X,Y,Z,W)=g(R(X,Y)Z,W)$, since the coordinate symmetries are a bit nicer. In local coordinates, we can write
$$R=R_{ijkl}dx^i\otimes dx^j\otimes dx^k\otimes dx^l.$$
In these coordinates the symmetries of the curvature tensor give us
$$R_{ijkl}=-R_{jikl},\quad R_{ijkl}=-R_{ijlk}.$$
In particular, we see that $R_{iikl}=R_{ijkk}=0$ for any indices $i,j,k,l$. In the case of $n=2$ we see that the indices can only take values $1$ or $2$ and **we find that $R_{1212}$ is the only nonzero coefficient of the Riemann curvature tensor** (and of course all of the other coefficients determined only from it). This is important since it tells us that in dimension 2 that the Riemann curvature tensor is determined entirely by the scalar curvature.

Since the Ricci curvature of $X,Y$ is just the trace of the map $Z\mapsto R(Z,X)Y$ it isn't hard to check that if $\rho=R_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$ in coordinates then 
$$R_{ij}=g^{kl}R_{kilj},$$
where $g^{ij}$ are the coefficients of $g^{-1}$ in coordinates. Similarly, one has that the scalar curvature is 
$$s=g^{rs}R_{rs}=g^{rs}g^{kl}R_{krls}.$$
Since $n=2$ we have $$R_{ij}=g^{11}R_{1i1j}+g^{12}R_{1i2j}+g^{21}R_{2i1j}+g^{22}R_{2i2j},$$
and so using the fact that $R_{1212}$ is the only nonzero coefficient we find that
\begin{align}
R_{11}&=g^{22}R_{2121}=g^{22}R_{1212},&&\qquad R_{12}=g^{21}R_{2112}=-g^{21}R_{1212},\\
R_{21}&=g^{12}R_{1221}=-g^{12}R_{1212},&&\qquad R_{22}=g^{11}R_{1212}.
\end{align}
To make everything easier at the end, suppose we are working in normal coordinates, i.e. $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$. Then $$s=R_{11}+R_{22}=2R_{1212},$$
and for any vector fields $X=X^i\partial_i$ and $Y=Y^i\partial_i$ written in these coordinates, we have
$$\rho(X,Y)=X^iY^jR_{ij}=(X^1Y^1+X^2Y^2)R_{1212} $$
and
$$s\langle X,Y\rangle=2(X^1Y^1+X^2Y^2)R_{1212}.$$
So we have the desired relationship $$\rho(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}s\langle X,Y\rangle.$$